# does spring-cloud-config support xml files as configuration?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

does spring-cloud-config support xml files as configuration file?

The documentation/examples mention only about yml files and properties files that can be used as configuration file. Is there a way by which xml file/any other format can also be supported (eg: by extending the spring-cloud-config?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Serving Plain Text Feature](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text) and request your xml (or any other format) using http.

Comment: is it possible to read an element from the XML file? like fetching a key from a properties/key-value yml file?

Comment: from what I investgated - no.